# C++ initialize/fill static member std::array elements to specific value

Tags: c++, arrays, static-members, array-initialization

I'm wondering if there is a proper way to do this.

Given the example:

```
struct Test {
    static std::array<unsigned, 123> data;
};

std::array<unsigned, 123> Test::data = {};
```

If I want to set all the elements in the `data` to some value, 5 for instance.

I could do something like this:

```
struct Test {
    static std::array<unsigned, 123> data;
private:
    static decltype(data) init_data_arr() {
        decltype(data) arr = {};
        arr.fill(5);
        return arr;
    }
};

std::array<unsigned, 123> Test::data = Test::init_data_arr();
```

But then I'd be allocating an extra arrays worth of memory and doing a copy on it all, which doesn't seem ideal.

Another less memory intensive option would be something like:

```
struct Test {
    static bool is_init;
    static std::array<unsigned, 123> data;

    Test() {
        if (!is_init) {
            is_init = true;
            data.fill(5);
        }
    }
};

bool Test::is_init = false;
std::array<unsigned, 123> Test::data = {};
```

But now I have additional overhead when constructing my Test struct.

Now I know you can initialize pod arrays like so: `std::array<int, 3> a = {1, 2, 3};` but for `N` sized arrays this would quickly become horrible to maintain.

Every solution I seem to come across just uses the `fill` member function on the array class but always treats the arrays as if they are non static member variables, or it initializes them in main, both of these don't really help my situation.

Edit:
I created this utility header that generalizes the 2nd option.
    #pragma once

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

namespace Utils {

    template<typename Container>
    using element_type_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()))>;

    template<class Container>
    static Container create_filled_container(const element_type_t<Container>& value) {
        Container container = {};
        std::fill(container.begin(), container.end(), std::move(value));
        return container;
    }

}
```

This could probably be improved more, but it seems to work. Usage is as follows:

```
std::array<unsigned, 123> Test::data = Utils::create_filled_container<decltype(data)>(456);
```

which sets all elements to whatever you specify.

Edit2:
So I did some more testing and it looks like calling a function to fill the array vs manually doing it doesn't always produce the same assembly.

I've setup a demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/IIppuA)!

Edit3:
Changed up some stuff so it could be constexpr, heres its current form:

```
template<class Container>
static constexpr Container create_filled_container(const element_type_t<Container>& value) {
    Container container = {};

    for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it)
        *it = value;

    return container;
}
```

which produces the same assembly now.

Comment: *But then I'd be allocating an extra arrays worth of memory and doing a copy on it all, which doesn't seem ideal.* Are you sure about that?  NRVO will elide that away and make it cost you nothing extra.  You should check the assembly to see if it does that.

Comment: @NathanOliver good call, I forgot to turn on optimizations when i was testing assembly generation. But you are right, it does produce the same assembly when -O3 is used for `Test::init_data_arr()` example vs {0, ..., n} initialization.

Comment: @NathanOliver So would you say that that would probably be the best way of going about this, or is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: It would be the way I would do it.  Its simple to understand, make maintenance easy, and should compile away.  Once the code is done, if you are unhappy with the performance, the profile and see where the issue is.  Most likely it wont be this.

Comment: @NathanOliver So after doing more testing, I found out that even on `-O3` optimization, depending on the datatype, for example char/float/int, the assembly created by the filled array function can change significantly over a the verbose arr = {1,2,3,...,n} initialization.

Comment: just initilaize it with a constexpr function. No run time code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize it with a constexpr function or lambda. No runtime code is generated.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned len, unsigned val>
constexpr std::array<unsigned, len> initialize_array()
{
    std::array<unsigned, len> ret{};
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        ret[i] = val;
    return ret;
}

struct Test {
    constexpr static std::array<unsigned, 123> data{ initialize_array<123,5>() };
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Test::data[4] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: OP's `data` is not even `const` though. (might just be the initial value, as const array of `5` is mostly useless).

Comment: @Jarod42  True, For non const memory one needs to inline the array, This is implicit for constexpr. Whether a compiler generates initialized data or not is not specified in either case, unfortunately. But it can. Generally, these sorts of initializations are best with lookup const tables. I've found them helpful and efficient with things like Galois arithmetic for error correction and such and have seen impressive optimizations. Over time C++ compilers have gotten better and that will likely continue.

Comment: @doug "whether the compiler generates initialized data or not is not specified in either case" I didn't actually realize this, I thought it was specified to occur before static initialization, but I guess you are right, they say only that it must happen "as if" it occurred before static initialization. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization